# In Joomla 3.4 how to change the template location?

Tags: templates

In Joomla 3.4 how to change the template location path? I copy a site from one sub-domain to another sub-domain on the same server (site folder and the database) but the second pules the template from the first domain- how to correct that?

The template is JM Lifestile (Joomla-Monster.com) and uses EF3 framework and Bootstrap grid system.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Cheers

Comment: have you try to change the configuration.php of your site? maybe you need to change it's configuration, like database field, prefix, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Copy over the following directory:

```
ROOT (old) / templates / your_name
```

to:

```
ROOT (new) / templates / your_template
```

---

Then login to your Joomla backend and go to:

> Extensions (top menu) >> Install >> Discover

Click the **Discover** button and your template should appear, which you an install

Comment: I did that, that's the problem - it still pules it from the old site.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Global Configuration that you have the new subdomain using the correct database.

```
System > Global Configuration > Server
```

It sounds like you copied everything over but forgot to change the configuration file to match the new database settings.

Comment: I didn't actually, it's the new site database. All the articles and menus are loading from the new site directory and database but the template - strange, isn't it.

Comment: It's kinda hard to think of anything else without some links. The only other thing I can think of is some weird server caching or browser caching maybe? Have you tried purging browser and Joomla cache by chance?

Comment: Well, non of those unfortunately. The first site is dancebg.info and the second is dancebg.eu. In the .eu site in (right click/Page View) you will see that the template is taken from the .info site and also the logo at the top left corner is missing - that's the issue. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Thank you to everyone answering my Q - I ended up rebuilding the site from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possible reasons:

1. Hardcoded links in the template files
2. Some parameter setting for the template. This can be changed in the /administrator - interface.
3. Something changed in the defines.php file of the installation.

The defines.php-file, if it exists, should be in the root folder of the joomla installation. It will override the defines.php - file in the /includes - folder. Here you can specify where the templates - folder should be.